# in Adobe CQ (AEM) how to iterate through a list of resources using `data-sly-list` and `data-sly-resource` in sightly?

Tags: aem, sightly

In AEM 6.1, with a structure like this:

```
 - Page
   - form node
     - parsys
       - node 1
       - node 2
       - ...
       - node n
```

The original form has the following code which works 
`<div data-sly-resource="${ 'parsys' @ resourceType='foundation/components/parsys' }" data-sly-unwrap>`

I'm trying to update the form component that injects something before the last `node n`. On the form node, I have the following code:

```
<div data-sly-list.children="${resource.listChildren}">
    <div data-sly-list.fields="${children.listChildren}">
        <div data-sly-test=${fieldsList.last}> DO SOMETHING BEFORE LAST NODE</div>
        <div data-sly-resource="${fields}"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `data-sly-resource` seems to cause the server to hang, with very high cpu usage while the browser is waiting for response. I have to terminate the server process and restart it.

I have tried `<div data-sly-resource="${fields @ resourceType = fields.resourceType}"></div>` but it doesn't seem to render the fields as expected.

Is this the right way of iterating through nodes?

---

Update: Looked in the massive error.log file, and it seems the CPU spike was caused by infinite loop of RecursionTooDeepException - which I don't see where the recursion is.

Comment: usually this would happen if a node contained a reference to itself (or its parent.)

Comment: Thanks @awadheshv for your reply. I can't see the node containing a referent to itself in CRX. Also by adding `@resourceType = fileds.resourceType` it outputs the input components, but not fully rendered (missing labels for inputs, etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Sightly documentation on the Resource block statement](https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/sightly-spec/blob/master/SPECIFICATION.md#229-resource), you need to pass in a path to the resource, either relative or absolute. I was able to make your code work by changing `<div data-sly-resource="${fields}"></div>` to `<div data-sly-resource="${fields.path}"></div>`.

```
<div data-sly-list.children="${resource.listChildren}">
    <div data-sly-list.fields="${children.listChildren}">
        <div data-sly-test=${fieldsList.last}> DO SOMETHING BEFORE LAST NODE</div>
        <div data-sly-resource="${fields.path}"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you haven't already downloaded the [Sightly REPL](https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/aem-sightly-repl), I would highly suggest it to test and debug scenarios such as this one.

Comment: You are the man! Adding ".path" fixed the problem! It would be nice if the server could throw something more meaningful to the log, instead of displaying a partially working page.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a Sling Model and return the data from child nodes as a list from it.

See this link for reference https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/models.html#collections

Comment: Thanks Danil for your answer.